# How to blacklist a specific version of a dependency in a cargo.toml file?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a dependency on an external library in my `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[dependencies]
foo = "0.5.6"
```

Unfortunately, the `foo` crate came out with a new release, `0.5.7`, that introduces a substantial regression. There should be a new version soon™, `0.5.8` which no longer has this bug. Is there a way that I can keep cargo from pulling the bad version? I know it is possible to specify "`0.5.6` or earlier", as in such:

```
[dependencies]
foo = "0.5.0, <0.5.7"
```

But is there  a way to also allow for `0.5.8` to be included, whenever it gets released?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Cargo does not allow this, and using `foo = "0.5.0, <0.5.7"` is your best bet for now. I personally wouldn't trust that a yet to be released version is definitely going to fix your problem anyway. As soon as the new version is releases and you have tested it, you can switch to `foo = "0.5.8"`.

You can also ask the crate author to yank version 0.5.7; Cargo won't select a yanked version, so it will use 0.5.6 as the most recent version until 0.5.8 is released. Yanking is the correct solution to deal with broken releases.